# When I set froala edit to 'off', the links in the editor stop working

Tags: froala

When displaying text with a link in the froala editor, if the editor is set as non-editable, the link does not work.

```
<script>function loadEditor(){ var frEditor = new FroalaEditor('#imessage', { height: 350, width: 500},function(){frEditor.edit.off();});}</script><body onload="loadEditor()"><div id="imessage"><p>Some text</p><p><a href="https://stackoverflow.com/" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">StackOverFlow</a></p></div></body>
```

Is there a setting required to enable the link to respond to a mouse-click while in read-only mode?

Comment: We're having the same issue. Were you able to resolve this? If so, please post your solution as an answer.

Comment: No solution found yet

Answer (score 0):

When initialising the editor, add a click function to the 'initialized' event to open the link:

```
events: {
    'initialized': function () {
        this.edit.off();
        //froala link doesn't work in readonly - workaround
        if ($('.fr-element').find('a').length > 0) {
            var linkobj = $('.fr-element').find('a')[0];
            var link = $(linkobj).prop('href');
            $('div.fr-element.fr-view.fr-disabled').click(function () { window.open(link); })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This helped in resolving an issue related to Opening YouTube videos added by link in Froala, in the initialization function, I added this for videos (tested it for multiple videos as well):

```
if ($('.fr-element').find('iframe').length > 0) {
    $('div.fr-element.fr-view').eq(0).on('click', function (e) {
        if ($(e.target).is('span') && $(e.target).find('iframe').length > 0) {
            var iframeSrc = $(e.target).find('iframe').attr('src');
            console.log('IFrame src:', $(e.target).find('iframe'));
            window.open(iframeSrc);
        }
    });
}
```